# Wordpress sendform throws 'Uncaught ReferenceError: sendform is not defined'

Tags: javascript, wordpress, send

I have made a form to login, that work in a normal HTML page. But when I put it into wordpress the submit button doesn't work. If I put the code into dreamweaver and open it in a browser it does work. Only in wordpress with the same code that doesn't work it says :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sendform is not defined

My code:

```
<div class="client-area"><form action="https://extranet.proden.com/Proden/Client-Area/LogSys/Log.asp" method="POST" name="LoginClient">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input tabindex="1" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {this.form.submit();}" type="text" name="Username" size="16" /></td>
<td rowspan="2"><a href="javascript:sendform()"><img style="box-shadow: none;" title="Submit login" alt="Submit login" src="http://altitudeconseil.ca/clients/proden/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/login_submit.png" width="61" height="50" />
</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input tabindex="2" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {this.form.submit();}" type="password" name="Password" size="16" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="autoLoginHidden" value="N" />
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: small;"><input id="Checkbox1" tabindex="3" type="checkbox" name="autoLogin" value="true" />Remember me (cookies must be enabled).</p>
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="English" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<p style="font-size: small;">Please enter your username and password. If you do not have access, please <a href="mailto:info@proden.com">contact us</a> and a profile will be created for you.</p>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendform() {
            if(document.LoginClient.autoLogin.checked)
                document.LoginClient.autoLoginHidden.value = "Y";
            else
                document.LoginClient.autoLoginHidden.value = "N";           
            document.LoginClient.submit()
        }
        //alert('For testing purposes the input fields are filled already.')

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cookies.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
var cookie = readCookie("ZC_login");
        if(cookie)
        {
            //window.status = 'username is : ' + document.LoginClient.Username.value + ' should be : ' + cookie;
            document.LoginClient.Username.value = cookie;
            document.LoginClient.Password.focus();

            var password = readCookie("ZC_password");
            var autoLogin = readCookie("ZC_autologin");
            if(autoLogin &#038;&#038; autoLogin == "Y")
            {               
                document.LoginClient.autoLogin.checked = true;
                document.LoginClient.Password.value = password;
                sendform();
            }
        } else {
            document.LoginClient.Username.focus();
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Wordpress phpmailer or sending forms from your Wordpress website via a contact form could be dead because of a few reasons. The most common.

- phpmailer is not enabled with your host -- or your running an off php version, or there is something strange going on at your server. Contact your host provider.
- Also there are tons of plugins that may be able to assist in the
  problem, that work by toggling your mail option to SMTP or by cleaning up an
  issue preventing success in phpmailer *(which also could be theme
  related as well)*

Check out some top rated WP mailer plugins: http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/phpmailer

If some well reviewed plugins don't work -- contact your host and they should be able to enable.

Additional resources:

- [phpmailer apache info](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html)
- [phpmailer issues in WP](http://wordpress.org/tags/phpmailer)
- [What is SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)
- [what is phpmailer](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/send-email-from-a-page/using-phpmailer-to-send-mail-through-php)